# User not found for SPO profile properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property

I am using UserProfilePropertiesForUser class to pull SharePoint profile properties of the user. However for some users, i am receiving user not found exception. I have just checked on the SharePoint site and can find the user even through check permissions.

Can someone please guide me what could be the possible root cause of this issue that i am getting user not found exception but the user can access the SPO site. I am also attaching the code and error screenshot for the reference.

```
var usr = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetByEmail("abc@constoo.com");
cxt.Load(usr); 
cxt.ExecuteQuery();
```

After the execute query call, i am getting the below exception.
[image]
Regards, Tayyab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SiteUsers will return you the user if user as visited the SharePoint list at least once. This is because it looks into UserInformationList which is present in every site collecction. You can try  Graph API instead .

```
import { graph } from '@pnp/graph';
import '@pnp/graph/users';

const getUser = await graph.users.getById('foo@contoso.com')();
```

Comment: The other possible solution would be "ensure user" before get it.

Comment: "... if user has visited the SharePoint list at least once..." or permissions was assigned to user directly (not via group) as I remember it right.

Comment: @Akshay: Thank you for adding details about how SiteUsers call works and sharing the Graph API solution.

Comment: @VIadilen: Awesome, ensure user call worked for me, appreciate your help.